# Python TypeError: changeMaster.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'parent'

Tags: python, tkinter

I've looked at different questions and have looked at different resources to solve my problem but I haven't been lucky as I'm fairly new with Python.
I'm trying to run my program at the very end with

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    check = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM masterpassword")
    # if there is already a present password 
    if check.fetchall(): 
        app = login()
    else: 
        app = changeMaster()

app.mainloop()
```

but I get an error that says:

```
TypeError: changeMaster.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'parent'
```

```
# change master password with correct input 
class changeMaster(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        # display config 
        self.geometry("400x400")
        self.title("change master password")

        # main menu button 
        back = Button(self, text="main menu", command=self.destroy).grid(padx=20, pady=30)

        # enter new password 
        Label(self, text="enter new password").place(x=250, y=300)
        self.newPass = Entry(width = 20)
        self.newPass.place(x=400, y=300)

        # re-enter password 
        Label(self, text="re-enter password").place(x=250, y=400)
        self.enter = Entry(width = 20)
        self.enter.place(x=400, y=400)
        
        # submit password 
        Button(self, text="submit", command=self.confirm).place(x=350, y=400)
    
    def confirm(self):
        # if the passwords match 
        if self.newPass.get() == self.enter.get():
            # new password is set to hashedPassword 
            hashedPassword = self.newPass.get()

            # inserts the new password into the database 
            insert_password = """INSERT INTO masterpassword(password)
            VALUES(?)"""
            
            # 
            cursor.execute(insert_password, [(hashedPassword)])
           
            # saves into database
            db.commit()

            # switch to the viewpassword window 
            window = viewPass(self)
            window.grab_set()
        else:
            Label(self, text="passwords do not match").place(x=375, y=500)
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to call `changeMaster()` with a value for `parent`.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I've tried making the value Tk, Toplevel and experimented with some other possible solutions but it hasn't been working. I'm not very sure which value I should be accessing in my class.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: you should first create main window `root = tk.Tk()` and later use it as parent in `app = changeMaster(root)`. OR you should use `Tk` to create this window `class changeMaster(Tk):` without using `parent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Toplevel` is for creating second window and it needs main window as parent.

So first you have to create main window and later use it as parent

```
root = Tk()

app = changeMaster(root)

root.mainloop()
```

---

If it has to be then only window then you should use `Tk` (without `parent`) instead of `Toplevel`

```
class changeMaster(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()    

    # ... code ...


app = changeMaster()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: if it helped then you may mark my answer as accepted.